# How to show that the rotation map $f$ is not a gradient of a convex function?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, analysis

Given space $X, Y\subset{R}^2,$ consider a map $f: x\mapsto Rx$ from $X$ to $Y$ that
$$
  R=\begin{bmatrix}
   \cos\theta &           -\sin\theta \\
    \sin\theta & \cos\theta
  \end{bmatrix}, \theta\in(0, \pi/2).
$$

> How to show that there does not exist a convex function such that its gradient is the map $f$(it is not a gradient at all)?

i.e. We cannot find a convex function $g$ such that $f= \nabla g$.

My idea:
We can get the Jacobian $Df(x)$ which is just $R$. Then $\det(Df(x))=\det(R)=1$. Then if we suppose that we have a convex function $g$ such that $f= \nabla g$. That means $Df(x)=\Delta g(x)\ge 0$. But I have no idea about the contradiction.

Comment: Hint: If $f = \nabla \phi= (\cos(\theta)x-\sin(\theta)y, \sin(\theta)x+\cos(\theta) y)$ then what is $\nabla\times f$? I don't have enough points to write a comment. Edit: I don't know why people downvote this. I wasn't asking for points. I just wanted to write a comment.

Comment: Have you considered finding the function $\phi$ such that $\nabla \phi = f$ and then show that $\nabla$ is not convex?

Comment: @KenHung Do you mean to show that $\phi$ is not convex?

Comment: @KenHung But it seems a similar idea...

Comment: Oh yes. Apology for my typo in the comment.

Comment: @KenHung So how to show $\phi$ is not convex...

Comment: Well. This direction is more closer to a constructive proof. Because you solve for the function $\phi$ directly and showing that it does not satisfy the property, whereas @Kai Chung’s idea did not explicitly find such $\phi$.

Comment: In what context do you encounter this question? Cause the method used to solve this question can be quite different.

Comment: @KenHung In convex analysis. Because there is a theorem A function is convex if and only if its gradient is monotone.

Comment: @KenHung I think that to find such $\phi$ is harder than contradiction.

Comment: Oh then you can use the theorem directly.

Comment: Does the question require $X$ and $Y$ be arbitrary? Cause I might have found convex function that satisfy the statement.

Comment: not really. Cause you can integrate the gradient function to get the original function, by using techniques i in multivariable calculus.

Comment: @KenHung $X, Y$ can be compact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose (for a contradiction) that there exists a function $F:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ such that $\nabla F(x) = f(x) = Rx$ for all $x \in \mathbb R^2$. Then the Hessian of $F$ is $R$. However, the Hessian must be symmetric, whereas $R$ is not symmetric. This is a contradiction.

Thus, there is no function $F:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ such that the gradient of $F$ is $f$.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Is the function $F$ convex? Because we need to show that $f$ is not the gradient of a convex function.

Comment: @Hermi If there's not a flaw in my logic, I believe I've proved that $f$ is not the gradient of any function $F:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$.

Comment: @littleO I think you are saying that the Hessian is symmetric because the mixed partials are equal. But the classic theorem which says that the second mixed partials are equal required $f$ to be $C^2$. If the second partials exist but are not continuous, the the mixed partials may not be equal.

Comment: @Blue If $\nabla F(x) = Rx$ for all $x \in \mathbb R^2$, then necessarily $F$ is $C^2$. For example, $\frac{\partial F(x)}{\partial x_1} = R_{11} x_1 + R_{12} x_2$, which is a linear function: perfectly smooth, perfectly nice. The second-order partial derivatives of $f$ are not just continuous, they are constant.

Comment: Oh of course thank you.