# Is there any function∇ f which is monotone but f does not exist or is not convex i.e counter example to [∇ f is monotone ⟹ f is convex ]?

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I tried making such piecewise functions but didn't work.There are answers ([How to show that the rotation map $f$ is not a gradient of a convex function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3841879/how-to-show-that-the-rotation-map-f-is-not-a-gradient-of-a-convex-function/3843260#3843260))saying that the rotation matrix which is skew symmetric is such an operator as the hessian should be symmetric but hessian and gradient are not the same isn't it?

Comment: What exactly is your question? I do not have any clue what you are trying to ask.

Comment: I updated the question. Is is clear now?

Comment: Please, do not write the question in the title. Write properly in the main text.

Answer (score 1):

If $f \colon \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ is differentiable, then
$f$ is convex if and only if $\nabla f$ is (maximal) monotone.

However, there are (maximal) monotone operators $A \colon \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$, which are not the gradient of a convex function.

Indeed, any skew symmetric $A$ works (here, we identify $A$ with the operator $x \mapsto A \, x$). If there would be a differentiable function $f \colon \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ with $\nabla f(x) = A\, x$, then $f$ would be twice differentiable with $\nabla^2 f(x) = A$. However, this contradicts symmetry of the Hessian.