# every positive monotone increasing function necessarily the derivative of a convex function?

Tags: convex-analysis, subgradient

I was trying to find out if every positive (do we need this?) monotone increasing function $f :\mathbb{R}_{+}\to\mathbb{R}_{+}$ was necessarily the derivative of a convex function.
I have found [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/514849/844467) that seems related but I am not so sure if this is the good approach. Do I have to verify that for $n$ points $x_1,\ldots, x_n$ I have $\langle x_0-x_1,f(x_0)\rangle+\ldots+\langle x_{n-1}-x_n,f(x_{n-1})\rangle+\langle x_{n}-x_0,f(x_n)\rangle\ge 0$? (for every  $f$ as above)

Comment: Any function $f :\mathbb{R}_{+}\to\mathbb{R}_{+}$ is necessarily positive

Comment: Hint: A function with increasing derivative is convex.

Comment: It slightly depends on your definition of derivative. $f(x) =x$ for $0 < x < 1$; $f(1)=3$; $f(x)=x+10$ for $x>1$ is a monotone increasing function but not obviously the derivative of its integral

Comment: you don't need positive. Check - $x^2$ has negative derivative for $x<0$, but you may want to add continuous to the requirement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $F: I \to \Bbb R$ is convex and differentiable on an interval $I \subset \Bbb R$ then $F'$ is increasing and *continuous,* see for example [Continuity of derivative of convex function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1901753/42969).

Conversely, if $f: I \to \Bbb R$ is increasing and continuous then
$$ \tag{*}
 F(x) = \int_a^x f(t) \, dt 
$$
(for some $a \in I$) is convex with $F'=f$.

If $f$ is only increasing but not necessarily continuous then we can still define $F$ via $(*)$ because monotone functions are Lebesgue integrable. Then $F' = f$ a.e. in $I$ and $F$ is convex: For $x < y < z$ is
$$
 \frac{F(y)-F(x)}{y-x} = \frac{1}{y-x} \int_x^y f(t) \, dt
= \int_0^1 f(x + s(y-x)) \, ds \\
\le f(y) \le \int_0^1 f(y + s(z-y)) \, ds = \frac{F(z)-F(y)}{z-y} \, .
$$

Comment: If $f$ is continuous I understand that $F$ is convex, since $F'=f$ and $f$ is increasing. But what is the argument in the case $F'=f$ a.e.?

Comment: @roi_saumon: I have added a sketch of the argument.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a typo $f'\to f$?

Comment: @roi_saumon: Yes, it should be $f$ (or $F'$). Hopefully correct now.