# For a vector-valued $f,$ is there a convex $\varphi$ such that $\nabla \varphi = f?$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, convex-analysis

Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be a convex open set.
Suppose a continuously differentiable vector-valued function $f : U \to \mathbb{R}^d$ satisfies that its derivative $D f : U \to \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$ is symmetric and positive semidefinite.
Is there a convex function $\varphi : U \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\nabla \varphi = f$?

I guess the answer is yes.
I attempted to show that $f$ is cyclically monotone, but I could show only the monotonicity as follows.
Let $x_1, \dots, x_k \in U.$
Then, Taylor's theorem says
$$
f(x_{i+1})
=
f(x_i)
+
\left(
\int_0^1
D f ((1 - s) x_i + s x_{i+1}) 
d s
\right)
(x_{i+1} - x_i)
.
$$
Thus, we have
$$
(x_{i+1} - x_i)^\prime
(f(x_{i+1}) - f(x_i))
=
(x_{i+1} - x_i)^\prime
\left(
\int_0^1
D f ((1 - s) x_i + s x_{i+1}) 
d s
\right)
(x_{i+1} - x_i)
\geq
0
$$
by the positive semidefiniteness of $D f.$

In this proof, the symmetry of $D f$ is not used, but I am not sure how it helps.

**EDIT:**
If $f$ is the gradient of some function, the monotonicity implies that the antiderivative is convex, but I am not assuming that $f$ is a gradient.
Also, if $f$ is linear, p.240 of Rockafellar's book claims the answer is yes.
I would like to know what happens if $f$ is nonlinear.

Comment: This discussion may help https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111767/is-every-monotone-map-the-gradient-of-a-convex-function

Comment: Since $Df$ is symmetric, there exists $\phi$ such that $\nabla \phi = f$ on the star-shaped set $U$ (classical vector calculus). Since $\nabla \phi$ is monotone, $\phi$ is convex (basic convex calculus). Do I miss something?

Comment: @daw Thank you! It's Poincare's lemma.